# How do I make a fully populated reference object in MongoDB using java spring annotations

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am getting a primary unique constraint error when I add the same object to a table in an array in my MongoDB table.  I really want the whole object in the array and not just a reference to it.

Ok so I have this case where I have a book table with lots of books each with an id as the primary key that is unique.

Book table:

```
{
 "_id" : "1234-sc-myKey",
 "title" : "Tom Sawyer",
 "author" : "Mark Twain"
}
```

Then I have a store table:

```
{
 "_id" : "myStoreId-1",
 "name" : "book store 1",
 "books" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : "1234-sc-myKey",
        "title" : "Tom Sawyer",
        "author" : "Mark Twain"
    },
    {
        "_id" : "5678-pc-myKey",
        "title" : "Huck Finn",
        "author" : "Mark Twain"
    }
  ]
 }
```

I get a primary key constraint error when I add the same book to another store. I know that I can do this annotation @DBRef and get the store table to look like this:

```
{
 "_id" : "myStoreId-1",
 "name" : "book store 1",
 "books" : [ 
    {
        "$ref" : "Book",
        "$id" : "1234-sc-myKey"
    } 
 }
```

But then I would have to query the database again for each book to get a list of titles.  Is there a way to have the books in the store table but also have a unique primary key on the books?  I am sure there is a cool java spring annotation for this but I am not finding it.

Java info:

class Book

```
@JsonAutoDetect
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Document(collection = "Book")
@CompoundIndexes({
    @CompoundIndex(name = "pk_idx", def = "{'bookId':1, 'type': 1, 'myKey': 1}", unique=true)
})
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Book {

 @Id
 private String id;
 etc...
}
```

class Store:

```
 @JsonAutoDetect
 @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
 @Document(collection = "Store")
 @Data
 @Builder
 @NoArgsConstructor
 @AllArgsConstructor
 public class Store {
  @Id
  private String id;
  private String name;
  //this is the solution where it throws unique constraint
  private List<Book> books;

  //this is the solution I don't like
  @DBRef
  private List<Book> books;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `@Reference` above  `private List<Book> books;` in class `Store`

Comment: YES! Thank you.  This is the annotation I needed to get a disconnected fully populated reference.  Much appreciated!